# Unable to see the error logs in AWS S3 - CocoaLumberjack

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, error-logging, cocoalumberjack

I am using CocoaLumberjack for logging errors in my app and storing these errors in Amazon AWS S3. It's is working perfectly fine as all the logs are indeed getting stored in S3. But whenever I click on any link to see error message, it shows this [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t28Hc.png). I also tried to print the logs in the Xcode console, and that worked as intended. Can anyone help me out with this? Also I am new to the stack overflow, so forgive me if I didn't state my question properly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your files on your S3 bucket are not public and can thus not be accessed through http.
You can make them public (if you want everyone to be able to collect your logs ...) or you have to access them through your s3 browser in the amazon console or the SDK.

You can read more about S3 access control:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html